# Basic Programming

Tags: c

I have a structure like this

```
for(..;..;..)
{
    if(true)
    {

    }
    //statements

}
```

I want to write a statement inside if except goto that will send the control only outside if and execute statements that I have marked.

Comment: You have to explain a little more. Do you need it to go only for that iteration, for the nest iteration, or for all the subsequent ones.

Comment: No not break because break in case of break the control will go outside the for loop altogether

Comment: Give a more detailed example..

Comment: What I mean is that i just want to come out of that if block and execute statements written at the place where I have mentioned //statements in my code

Comment: May be put the if inside a do while and use break. Though i cant say for sure if this is what you want. Explain more.

Comment: I am not facing any issues this is just a question out of curiosity.
What I want to know is if its possible that I get into the if block and then write a statement that will send the control to out of if bloc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to handle this situation is to put the body of the `if` statement into a separate function, and then return from the middle of the function if, for some reason, the function is unable to finish. After the function returns, the remainder of the statements in the `for` loop will run.

```
void foo(void)
{
    //statements
    //statements

    if ( something_bad_happened )
        return;

    //statements
    //statements

    if ( some_other_bad_thing_happened )
        return;

    //statements
    //statements
}

void bar(void)
{
    for(..;..;..)
    {
        if ( some_foo_is_needed )
            foo();

        //statements
        //statements
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put your if inside a dummy `do..while` loop like this:

```
for(..;..;..)
{
    do
    {
        if ()
        {
            //use break somewhere here according to your logic
        }
    }while(false);

    //statements
}
```

This will cause the `break` to only skip the inner `do..while` loop.

The condition is `false` in `do..while` so that the loop runs only once as is expected in case of a normal if. The loop is there just to allow a `break` in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an if, use a switch statement. You can break out of a switch at any point. This isn't a very practical solution... but it works.

```
for(..;..;..)
{
    switch(boolean_expression) { //break just leaves this switch statement
    case 0: //false is 0

        break;
    default: //true is not zero
        //statements
        if(something) 
            break;
        //statements you want to skip
        break;
    }
    //statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, that you want to write a statement inside `if` and *goto* your marked statements only if that condition is true, then a `goto` statement can be useful, if for instance `//statements` only need to be run if the condition is true:

```
for(..;..;..)
{
    if(true)
    {
        goto dothis;
    }
    /* other statements */
    return A;

    dothis:;
    //statements

    return B;
}
```

The `//statements` need not be in the `for` loop with `goto`, for example:

```
for(..;..;..)
{
    if(true)
    {
        goto dothis;
    }
    /* other statements */
}
return A;

dothis:;
//statements

return B;
```